# How to carry on build execution in jenkins ignoring the passed steps after fixing a failed step

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

As a part of CI/CD activity, I am migrating a project from Build Forge to Jenkins. Since I am new to jenkins, I am confused as to how to continue execution in Jenkins from a failed step, ignoring the previously passed steps. Or is it that all the steps should rerun from the beginning? Appreciating any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is with the Cloudbees Checkpoints plugin, which is not open source. You would have to use the Cloudbees version of Jenkins:

https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html?q=checkpoints#workflow

Comment: Or is it possible to handle this with some groovy script? Btw thanks for the cloudbees suggestion. Am going through it also.